# preg_match_all: get text inside quotes except in html tags

Tags: html, regex, tags, quotes

I've recently used a pattern to replace straight double quotes by pairs of opening/closing double quotes.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\")([^\"]+)(\")/','“$2”',$string);
```

It works fine when $string is a sentence, even a paragraph.

But…

My function can be called to to the job for a chunk of HTML code, and it's not working as excepted anymore:

```
$string    = preg_replace('/(\")([^\"]+)(\")/','“$2”','<a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>');
```

returns

```
<a href=“page.html”>Something “with” quotes</a>
```

And that's a problem…

So I thought I could do it in two passes: extract text within tags, then replace quotes.

I tried this

```
$pattern='/<[^>]+>(.*)<\/[^>]+>/';
```

And it works for instance if the string is

```
$string='<a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>';
```

But it's not working with strings like:

```
$string='Something "with" quotes <a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>';
```

Any idea?

*Bertrand*

Comment: [THE PONY HE COMES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Kolink I know this would come up. That's why I would suggest to use simplexml and only apply it to the text not to the attributes.

Comment: The string I have to "clean" is the value of a text field in 90% of the case and in some cases you have "bits" of html code inside. That's why parsing is inappropriate.

Comment: What should be the desired output in case of `'Something "with quotes <a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>'` ? `'Something “with quotes <a href="page.html">Something ”with" quotes</a>'` or `'Something "with quotes <a href="page.html">Something “with” quotes</a>'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Usual reply I guess... As it has been already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), you should not parse HTML through Regex. You can take a look at the [PHP Simple DOM Parse](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract the text and apply your regex, which from what you have already said, seems to be working just fine.

[This](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/PHP_HTML_DOM_parser/PHPHTMLDOMParser.cc_09-07-2011.php3) tutorial should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using a parser when I need to parse some code. In that case, parsing the code won't help me replace some characters by others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that this will end in a flame war but this works:

```
echo do_replace('<a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>')."\n";
echo do_replace('Something "with" quotes <a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>')."\n";

function do_replace($string){
    preg_match_all('/<([^"]*?|"[^"]*")*>/', $string, $matches);
    $matches = array_flip($matches[0]);

    $uuid = md5(mt_rand());
    while(strpos($string, $uuid) !== false) $uuid = md5(mt_rand()); 
    // if you want better (time) garanties you could build a prefix tree and search it for a string not in it (would be O(n)

    foreach($matches as $key => $value)
        $matches[$key] = $uuid.$value;

    $string = str_replace(array_keys($matches), $matches, $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/\"([^\"<]+)\"/','&ldquo;$1&rdquo;', $string);
    return str_replace($matches, array_keys($matches), $string);
}
```

output (I replaced &ldquo; and  &rdquo; with `“` and `”`):

```
<a href="page.html">Something “with” quotes</a>
Something “with” quotes <a href="page.html">Something “with” quotes</a>
```

With a costum state machine you could even do it without the first replace and than replace back. I recomment to use a Parser anyway.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thanks. The thing is that in 90% of the time it's only a string I get (value from a text input) and working with parsers for a string or few tags needs actually more work. This regex is not meant to be used for a complete html page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way:

1. extract text that can be inside, or outside (before, after) any tag (if any)
2. use a callback to find quotes by pair and replace them.

code

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[^<>]*(?!([^<]+)?>)/sim', create_function('$matches',  'return preg_replace(\'/(\")([^\"]+)(\")/\', \'“$2”\', $matches[0]);'), $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand, resurrecting this question because it had a simple solution that lets you do the replace in one go—no need for a callback. (Found your question while doing some research for a general question about [how to exclude patterns in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).)

Here's our simple regex:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|"([^"]*)"
```

The left side of the alternation matches complete `<tags>` then deliberately fails. The right side matches double-quoted strings, and we know they are the right strings because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This code shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/wkd60c)):

```
<?php
$regex = '~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|"([^"]*)"~';
$subject = 'Something "with" quotes <a href="page.html">Something "with" quotes</a>';
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,"“$1”",$subject);
echo $replaced."<br />\n";
?>
```

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)